# Macbook PRO 2017 touchbar - Screen won't turn on sometimes

Tags: screen, macbook-pro

Sometimes when I open the lid of my MBP, the screen won't turn on.
No black screen - the screen is just completely off.

macOS is definitely running on the background, since I hear sounds, the touch bar is active, and I can use the caps lock key - the light goes on and off.

To get it working I close and open the lid again multiple times, until the screen comes up.

I wonder if this is a sign that I'll have a bricked MPB soon.

Comment: Have you tried using the screen brightness keys to brighten the screen when it does this?

Comment: Yes, through the touchbar but the screen is completely off, so it does nothing

Answer (score 1):

These symptoms sounds like a [flimsy display cable issue](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/flexgate-macbook-pro-display-issue/) - where backlight shutdown occurs after opening the display to a certain degree.

If so, you'd unfortunately have to get your whole screen replaced. AFAIK, Apple only has a replacement program for 2016 MBP models despite it affecting later models as well. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @njboot, I've looked into the flexgate problem before, altough, I really dont have the vertical bottom light that never goes out effect over here.

Comment: @queroga_vqz can you connect the machine to an external display? Set it to mirror screens and try/wait to reproduce the problem. If only the MBP screen goes black and the other display is unaffected, you can isolate the issue to the display hardware.

Comment: great idea, @njboot, I'll try that.